# Mavericks has wrong Russian layout

Tags: keyboard, macos

Looks like the Russian layout included in Mavericks has wrong characters mapping. The layout image in preferences looks correct (see the image). But actual mapping of punctuation characters resembles the DOS ones a decade ago. E.g., to enter comma or dot i need to press Shift-6 and Shift-7 respectively, instead of Shift-? and ?.
This was a forced upgrade from previous mac os x version by my company. Any ideas how to install correct Russian layout?

[image: Russian layout]

Comment: Is the layout also missing the ё, by chance?  In any case, you can remap the keys with http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Comment: Yes, it has been missing ё even before the upgrade. I'm currenty using KeyRemap4MacBook to map Caps Lock to layout switch (to have the same setting on both Mac and Linux).
But i found no way to add ё using KeyRemap4MacBook. Will Ukelele allow me to map Caps to layout switch?

Comment: I made a layout with ukelele to add that character which you can try:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46870715/k/RussianPC.keylayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Russian PC layout works correctly.  It sounds like you are using Russian instead.  Make sure you have the Russian flag with the PC underneath showing at the top right of the screen.  Or that you have the layout called Russian removed from your active Input Sources.

If you have the right flag showing, do you have this problem for all apps including TextEdit?

Comment: Thank you!
For some reason Russian was grayed out after i had added it for the 1st time, and only Russian - PC was available (as in attached image from the 1st post), which in fact was functioning as Russian. But now when i opened keyboard preferences and removed Russian, i was able to add Russian - PC. There's still no ё, but i can survive :)

Answer (score 1):

with "Russian PC" keyboard you can type "ё" by holding "е" and then pressing 1. Dunno how I guessed that, but it works. Much better then having ".," up there on numbers.

Comment: surely we have to use "shift" to type "ё" and dot because there is not enough keys on a 104 key PC keyboard. Sigh.